# Store multiple values in a single variable in linux

Tags: bash, for-loop

I need to store multiple command outputs that comes from a for loop into a single variable.
The variable should store the output separated by space.

Output that I am expecting:

```
for i in a b c d e
do
    xyz=$i
done
echo $xyz should return a b c d e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate strings

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# initialize xyz to empty
xyz=
for i in a b c d e
do
  # concatenate xyz space and i into xyz
  xyz="$xyz $i"
done
# remove the extra leading space from xyz
xyz="${xyz# }"
echo "$xyz should return a b c d e"
```

Or with growing the arguments array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# clear arguments array
set --

for i in a b c d e
do
  # add i to arguments array
  set -- "$@" "$i"
done

# expand arguments into xyz
xyz="$*"

echo "$xyz should return a b c d e"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use an array instead of var

```
for i in a b c d e
do
    arr+=("$i")
done
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: This is ok, but expanding with `echo "${arr[*]}"` would reflect more on the intent of concatenating the output rather than printing individual values (even though `echo` effectively concatenates the output of its arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve the problem:

```sh
for i in a b c d e
do
    xyz="$xyz$sep$i"
    sep=" "
done
echo "$xyz"
```

Here is the output:

```
a b c d e
```

Here is how it works. At first, both variables `xyz` and `sep` are unset, so expanding them (that is, `$xyz` and `$sep`) leads to empty strings. The `sep` variable represents a separator which is empty initially.

After the first iteration, the `xyz` variable is set to `a` and the `sep` variable is set to   (a space). Now for the second and subsequent iterations, the separator is a space, so now `xyz="$xyz$sep$i"` appends a space and the new value of `$i` to the existing value of `$xyz`. For example, in the second iteration, `xyz="$xyz$sep$i"` expands to `xyz="a b"`.

Of course, another alternative that avoids altering the separator value between iterations is as follows:

```sh
for i in a b c d e
do
    xyz="$xyz $i"
done
xyz="${xyz# }"
echo "$xyz"
```

Once again the output is:

```
a b c d e
```

In this alternative solution, the separator is always a space. But that means that in the first iteration of `xyz="$xyz$sep$i"` adds a leading space to `$xyz`, that is, after the first iteration, the value of the `xyz` variable is  `a` (note the leading space). The final value of the variable thus becomes  `a b c d e` (note the leading space again). We get rid of this leading space with the `${xyz# }` syntax which removes the smallest prefix pattern.

See [POSIX.1-2008: Shell Command Language: 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for more details on parameter expansion and prefix pattern removal.

Comment: Shouldn't you define `$sep` _before_ you use it in `$xyz`?

Comment: @arco444 If we do that, a leading space will be added to `$xyz`. The final value of `$xyz` will then be `" a b c d e"`, that is, there will be a leading space that we have to get rid of using prefix removal in this manner in the end: `${xyz# }`.